# Reading Excel file - No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, excel-2010, oledb

UPDATE:

after updating the correct path, I'm getting the new error which says
`"External table is not in the expected format."`

I'm not sure what is wrong with this code and I'm trying to read the excel sheet and below is my code and getting the following error.

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection();
string path =  Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/InformationNew.xlsx"));

oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

oledbConn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [epic],[desc] FROM [Sheet1$]";
oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oleda.Fill(ds); //<<<ERROR
```

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> ```
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before. Make sure your spreadsheet name is correct (if you're off by one character it won't work), your column names are correct, and your path is valid.

Wrap your data access in a Try...catch...finally block and you can probably get more error data.

Comment: I was pointing to the wrong one but now I'm pointing to the correct excel file i am getting this error `"External table is not in the expected format."`

Comment: Just to test - how about you try 'select * ' instead of the column names? (If you don't have spaces in the names, the brackets may be throwing you off)

Comment: Column name and select column must be same.