# Getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' while reading data from Excel sheet using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, odbc

Here is my excel sheet.

[image]

Now I want to read the excel and export the data in database but getting the error while executing cmd.ExecuteReader() command. 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Code written is below.

```
using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name], [Key], [Value], [AuditInsertTimestamp], [AuditInsertUserName], [AuditInsertAppName], " +
                    "[AuditUpdateTimestamp], [AuditUpdateUserName], [AuditUpdateAppName] from [LookUpInsertion$]", excelConnection))
                {
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(stCon))
                        {
                            //Give your Destination table name 
                            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "[DM].[Lookup]"; //Key   Value   AuditInsertTimestamp    AuditInsertUserName AuditInsertAppName
                            //AuditUpdateTimestamp  AuditUpdateUserName AuditUpdateAppName

                            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Excel file - No value given for one or more required parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237637/reading-excel-file-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Comment: Column A (Row Header) is empty which is what is probably giving the error.  OleDb is using Column A as a Key into a dictionary and you cannot have a dictionary with no Key.  I think you can fix issue by modifying the Connection String.